# Unable in getting data from list containing many objects

Tags: python, django, request, django-rest-framework

I am trying request.data.get('student_name') but it says that list has no attribute get. I just want to get the name of all students before passing to the serializer. I am sending the POST request data in the form of

```
[
{"student_name": "jack", "last_name": "cale", "fathers_name":"carlos"},
{"student_name": "alex", "last_name": "magasa", "fathers_name":"greg"},
{"student_name": "sia", "last_name": "gunns", "fathers_name":"brett"},
{"student_name": "jacob", "last_name": "woods", "fathers_name":"john"}
]
```

my views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_students(request):
student_name = request.data.get('student_name')
fathers_name = request.data.get('fathers_name')
serializer = StudentsSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return Response("success")
else:
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```

my serializers.py

```
class StudentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Students
    fields = ('student_name', 'last_name', 'fathers_name')
```

my models.py

```
class Students(models.Model):
student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
fathers_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Comment: `request.data[0].get('student_name')` would get the job done, but it would access the data of first element in the list, what would you like to do with all other elements ?

Comment: exactly @zdar i tried it but i am looking to it get all elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get value from list so you have to iterate through list

```
for data in request.data:
    student_name = data.get('student_name')
    father_name = data.get('father_name')
```

Comment: thnxx that was accurate

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a question about the format of the request object. My two cents is that it's worth throwing in an `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` at the beginning of the method, and then using `print` and `dir` to get an idea of what the object looks like. Since Django has so many django-specific objects, this helps in a lot of cases.